# Mockito: stubbing long call stack

Tags: java, unit-testing, ide

I have a service in which injected many other objects(which should be mocked), and I need to write unit test on some method. The problem is, that this method use many other methods in this service so I need to write many lines like `when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn(someValue)`. I had to write about 12 lines like above, and I manually copy-pasted those from 5 methods which used by method I test.

It's very troublesome to manually track which method will be called next, and I wonder if three some IDE plugin where I can specify start and end of execution for particular test case and it shows objects which need to be mocked?

I can't test each method separately, because most of methods in call stack is private, and I need to test exception which thrown by last method in call stack.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you need to mock so many things this is clear signal you need to refactor. So I assume you are not in position to refactor that code at the moment.

I don't think there are plugins to do that. Such plugin would need to execute the code to figure our all dependencies that should be mocked as some things that require mocking becomes visible in runtime only.

If I work with legacy code like this and can't refactor right now I use the test itself to help me find all the mocks like this using `Mockito`:

Configure [automatic mocks injection](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.16.0/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) with `@InjectMocks`

```
@InjectMocks private MyService sut;
```

Create your test:

```
@Test
public void testSomething() {
    sut.doSomething();

    // assert something
}
```

Now the goal is to make your assertion fail by adding required mocks. Just run the test. It will fail most probably with `NullPointerException` on invocation of some mock.

Add that mock just before the test method (this assumes that `MyService` uses fields or setters based injection):

```
@Mock private SomeDependency someDependency;

@Test
public void testSomething() {
    sut.doSomething();

    // assert something
}
```

Rerun the test. If `SomeDepenency` is just invoked and default value returned by it is enough you'll hit the next unmocked depenedency and handle it the same way.

If it is required to return some specific value from the mock invocation you add a configuration of the mock in a test:

```
when(someMock.someMethod()).thenReturn(someValue)
```

You repeat this until you get the assertion failure you created at the very beginning.

Then I move all defined mocks to the beginning of the test class.

Comment: I can use this approach, but it's almost the same as I did - manually check which method is called.